# How would I generate a list of distinct HTML tags in a page using JavaScript (must work in IE6)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The end result I'm after is a JavaScript array containing a list of tag names that are used in the HTML document eg:

div, span, section, h1, h2, p, etc...

I want the list to be distinct and I'm not interested in tags within the `<head>` of the document (but they can be there if it's a performance hog to exclude them).

This has to work in IE 6, 7, & 8 and I don't want to use jquery.

What would be the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Why do you not want to use jQuery? It supports IE 6.

Comment: I don't want jQuery to be a dependancy.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is `document.all.tagName`
At the top of my head, a for loop like this should do it (providing that you're gonna filter the tags you don't want on that list)

```
for(i = 0; i < document.all.length; i++)
{
  console.log(document.all[i].tagName);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, `document.all` is soooo cross browser. Not! :-) Use `getElementsByTagName('*')` instead and you get **all** browsers, not juse IE and friends.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a cross-browser solution:

```
var tags = {};  // maintains object of tags on the page and their count
var recurse = function(el) {
    // if element node
    if(el.nodeType == 1) {
        if(!tags[el.tagName])
            tags[el.tagName] = 0;
        tags[el.tagName]++;    
    }   
    // recurse through the children
    for(var i = 0, children = el.childNodes, len = children.length; i < len; i++) {
        recurse(children[i]);
    }
}

recurse(document);


// if you want just what's in the body(included)
var bodies = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
for(var i = 0; i < bodies.length; i++)
    recurse(bodies[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a unique list of tagnames in a document as an array that works in all browsers back to IE 6 and equivalent:

```
function listTagNames() {
  var el, els = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
  var tagCache = {};
  var tagname, tagnames = [];

  for (var i=0, iLen=els.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    tagname = els[i].tagName.toLowerCase();

    if ( !(tagname in tagCache) ) {
      tagCache[tagname] = tagname;
      tagnames.push(tagname);
    }  
  }
  return tagnames;
}
```

If you think there might be an inherited object property that is the same as a tag name, use a [`propertyIsEnumerable`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.7) test:

```
      if (!tagCache.propertyIsEnumerable(tagname)) {
```

so it will work even in Safari < 2.

Answer (score 0):

Get all tagnames in the document, unique, crossbrowser, plain js:

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('*'), tags = [], tmp = {}
for (var i=0;i<els.length;i+=1){
 if (!(els[i].tagName in tmp)){
   tags.push(els[i].tagName);
   tmp[els[i].tagName] = 1;
 }
}
```

use

```
if (!(els[i].tagName in tmp) 
     && !/head/i.test(els[i].parentNode.tagName) 
     && !/html|head/i.test(els[i].tagName))
```

to exclude the `<head>`